# pool game in java how to put 15 balls

Tags: java, trigonometry

I want to make pool game in java, I want to form 15 balls in a shape of pyramid that face up to left in center of table, but I don't know how to. I have to find the right coordinate of (x,y) to put balls in center of the table

[image]

I see someone code, and found this solutions.

```
  public class cek {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++) {
           int row = (int) Math.floor((Math.sqrt(1+8*i)/ 2)); // Using quadratic equation formula

            int x = (- (10 * (5- row)));
           System.out.println(i);
           System.out.println(Math.sqrt(1 + 8 * i));
           System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

}
```

result :

```
0
1.0
-50
1
3.0
-40
2
4.123105625617661
-30
3
5.0
-30
4
5.744562646538029
-20
5
6.4031242374328485
-20
6
7.0
-20
7
7.54983443527075
-10
8
8.06225774829855
-10
9
8.54400374531753
-10
10
9.0
-10
11
9.433981132056603
0
12
9.848857801796104
0
13
10.246950765959598
0
14
10.63014581273465
0
15
11.0
0

first ball [0]: -50 

ball 1-15: 
-40,-30,-30,-20,-20,-20,-10,-10,-10,-10,0,0,0,0
```

as you can see this could produce x coordinate for balls 1-15 like in first row 1 balls, second row 2 balls, third row 3 balls, 4th row 4 ball, 5th row 5th balls, but how can he come up with that solution and equation??
even after i see the solutions, i think it take me 1 day long to just figure out that code
and I am thinking I will never come up with that solution
especially 
`int row = (int) Math.floor((Math.sqrt(1+8*i)/ 2));`

im trying to produce code above, this all i can think..

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
               k=2*i+1-i;//10 20 30 40  50
               int x=-(n*10)+k*10;
               System.out.println(k);
               System.out.println(x);
               for(int r=1;r<k;r++) {
                  System.out.println(x);
              }

        }
```

but if i want to call ball class with parameter 1-15 and make object of new ball from it from another class, and the ball class will set (x,y) coordinate for each 1-15 balls in constructor.. this wont work..

```
int row = (int) Math.floor((Math.sqrt(1+8*i)/ 2)); // Using quadratic equation formula
```

this work..

update:
by using trigonometry to arrange the pyramid ball
i manage to make

[image]

```
     private double rowx(int rowNumber) {
            return rowNumber * (Math.sqrt(5) * r);
        }

     private void generateBalls(){
       balls=new ArrayList<Ball2>();
       int ballid=0;
       indexOfWhiteBall=0;
       if (balls.size()==0)
       {
          int x= Helper.BX + Helper.SW / 4 - r;
          int y = Helper.BY + Helper.SH / 2 - r;
          Ball2 balle=new Ball2(pinball,ballid,(Helper.BX + Helper.SW / 4 - r),Helper.BY + Helper.SH / 2 - r,r);
          balls.add(balle);
          balls.get(0).iswhiteball=true;
          ballid++;

       }
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
          double y= rowx(i);
          for(double x:rowY(i)) {

              Ball2 balle=new Ball2(pinball,ballid,(Helper.BX + (2.5*Helper.SW)/4 ) +y,(Helper.BY + Helper.SH / 2) +x,r);
              balls.add(balle);
              ballid++;
              System.out.print(balle + " ");

          }
      }
    }
     private double[] rowY(int rownum) {

            switch(rownum) {
         case 0: return new double[] {0};
         case 1:return new double[] {-r,r};
         case 2:return new double[] {-2*r,0,2*r};
         case 3: return new double[] {-3*r, -r, r, 3*r};
         case 4: return new double[] {-4*r, -2*r, 0, 2*r, 4*r};
         case 5:return new double[] {Helper.BX + Helper.SW / 4 - r};
         default:throw new IllegalArgumentException("no more than 5");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Might this question be better on [math.se]? For three balls, the centres form an equilateral triangle, so simple trigonometry will give you the coordinates

Comment: You need to express the coordinates of all the balls in term of the ball radius. As @KenY-N mentioned they form equilateral triangles. All you need is Pythagoras theorem. Start by making a drawing and draw your triangles. Set the top ball at (0,0)

Comment: I forgot, the equilateral triangles have sides of size 2*radius.

Comment: Just to ease your mind a little: even as someone who has programmed for quite a few years, these kind of things often take me _days_ to figure out on my own. I usually have to sit down with lots of scrap paper and my high school math book, but eventually get the hang of it. Are there others who can do it in 5 minutes, without looking up anything? Probably. But don't let that stop you. Take your time and you'll figure it out. Next time around, you'll be faster. And as a general tip for problem solving: break the problem down into smaller problems, solve each one.

Comment: Also, the above picture might be misleading as that table is weirdly small. If we're talking 8-ball, which I think we are, [this image](https://i.imgur.com/H3gZC0y.png) might be more helpful to find a place to start.

Comment: @domsson thankyou, Im amazed with all game programmer, but if to finish only this part need a day or two, then how can i finish the rest like when the ball is hit by the cue etc..

Comment: @kili that's why most don't write their games from scratch but use engines that do the heavy lifting like physics. But also, once you've figured out how something works, the next time around it will be much easier and faster, _plus_ you will be able to apply the logic and knowledge to similar problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

As you can see if you link the centres of the circles, you get equilateral triangles.

Considering the small one on top. It has sides of size `2*r`, and its height `h` can be calculated using the Pythagoras theorem: `h^2 = r^2 + (2*r)^2`. So `h` = `sqrt(5) * r`, so that is the y coordinate for the second row.

Also the balls are shifted on the x axis by `r`

So if the first ball centre is `(0, 0)`, the centres of 2 balls on the second row are `(-r, sqrt(5)*r)` and `(r, sqrt(5)*r)`.

You can now apply the same principle and calculate the centres of the other balls.

So now, please provide some code to implement this (by editing your question). If you show effort, we can help you further to get the code right.

**Implementation**

Assuming you have a Ball class as follows:

```
class Ball {
    private final int id;
    private final double x, y;

    public Ball(int id, double x, double y) {
        this.id = id;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Ball{ id=" + id +"(x=" + x +", y=" + y + ") }";
    }
}
```

You can have a `setupBalls` on your Pool class that reads like this: (I added printlns to help understand how it goes, all balls are added to the  `balls` list)

```
public class Pool {

    private static double r = 20;

    private void setupBalls() {
        List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();
        int ballId = 0;

        // for each row
        for(int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber<5; rowNumber++) {
            System.out.print("Row "+rowNumber + ": ");

            // get the Xs of the balls in that row, 
            // and create a ball for each
            double y = rowY(rowNumber);
            for(double x : rowXs(rowNumber)) {
                Ball ball = new Ball(ballId, x, y);
                balls.add(ball);
                System.out.print(ball + " ");
                ballId++;
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // Returns the Y of a given row 
    private double rowY(int rowNumber) {
        return rowNumber * (Math.sqrt(5) * r);
    }

   // Returns the list of the Xs for the balls on the given row 
   private double[] rowXs(int rowNumber) {
        switch (rowNumber) {
            case 0: return new double[] {0};
            case 1: return new double[] {-r, r};
            case 2: return new double[] {-2*r, 0, 2*r};
            case 3: return new double[] {-3*r, -r, r, 3*r};
            case 4: return new double[] {-4*r, -2*r, 0, 2*r, 4*r};
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("no more than 5 rows");
        }
    }

}
```

Then use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Pool().setupBalls();
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much! so you count the coordinate from the top (0,0) to last ball in fifth row right?

Comment: last ball on the bottom right would be `(4*r, 4*h)`, that is `(4*r, 4*sqrt(5)*r)`. Can you see that?

Comment: @kili I added an example implementation

Comment: thankyou so much i implement your code and i manage to make the table and balls thanks!!!!!

Comment: @kili Welcome, glad this helped